# Error reading the sector 0x19b8140

Tags: boot, keyboard

My laptop just has 32gb and I wanted today to install unity.
But I needed 2gb more.
So I followed an tutorial ➡️ [Here](https://itsfoss.com/free-up-space-ubuntu-linux/)
When I did step 3-5 the network began to automatically disconnect, and didn't work anymore, when I restarted it went for 3 minutes. The same thing everytime.
When I restarted it after 2 hours not using, it went to this error.
The problem is that my docking Keyboard don't work(while that 2 hours I opened it but don't saw anything broke).
So I'm using an Bluetooth keyboard.
But in booting Bluetooth isn't active.
So I can't get in the rescue mode.
Does anyone know how to fix?
Kenan K.